# Handle for Category page when filter is applied

Tags: magento-1.7, category, layered-navigation, filter, seo

I want to set

```
<action method="setRobots">
    <value>NOINDEX,FOLLOW</value>
</action>
```

For category page but **only when any filter is selected.**

So I did the following..

```
<catalog_category_layered translate="label">
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setRobots">
            <value>NOINDEX,FOLLOW</value>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

But it's loading that tag **when any filter is not selected.**

So basically

When URL is like as following

```
http://www.example.com/category/cate1.html
```

I want to it to be indexed. But when URL is like following

```
http://www.example.com/category/cate1.html?size=xl
```

I don't want it be indexed.

Any suggestion what should I do??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative you can use an helper method to check if filters are being applied.

```
<catalog_category_layered translate="label">
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setRobots">
            <value helper="module/getRobots" />
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

For that you need to create a custom module.

`Vendor/Module/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Vendor_Module>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Vendor_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <module>
                <class>Vendor_Module_Helper</class>
            </module>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

Then in your module helper file `Vendor/Module/Helper/Data`:

```
<?php

class Vendor_Module_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {
    public function getRobots()
    {
        $filters= Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getState()->getFilters();
        if (!is_array($filters)) {
            return 'NOINDEX,FOLLOW';
        } else {
            return 'INDEX,FOLLOW';
        }
    }
}
```

It's **possible that this code does not work because the catalog layer singleton has not been instantiated yet.**

If it's the case, I suggest you use the following code to **check whether or not a GET parameter is being applied to the URL**:

```
<?php

class Vendor_Module_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {
    public function getRobots()
    {
        $requestUri = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRequestUri();
        if (strpos($requestUri, "?") !== false) {
            return 'NOINDEX,FOLLOW';
        } else {
            return 'INDEX,FOLLOW';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, Let me try and will let you know soon. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please tell me in which files I should make changes for  getRobots() function?? I'm newbie for Magento..

Comment: @KaushalSuthar you shouldn't have to but let me know if you get unwanted results

Comment: I'm learning Magento, For getRobots() function I've made changes in app\code\local\Mage\Page\Block\Html\Head.php but I guess $filters is empty all the time, and then in local.xml

Comment: @KaushalSuthar I think you misunderstood my answer, do not edit `app\code\local\Mage\Page\Block\Html\Head.php` you need to create your own custom module, see my edit

Comment: This line Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getState()->getFilters(); returns an empty array all the time even if filter is applied. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @KaushalSuthar see my updated answer

Comment: It's worked properly now, Nice quick patch but it will not work when listening mode is changed like list & Grid because we just match '?', anyways that listing mode thing I'll consider in that condition, Thanks you so much. Now following http://www.digital-pianism.com/en/blog regulary :)

Comment: @KaushalSuthar haha thanks I don't post a lot of stuff on the blog, I'm more active on Twitter ;)

Comment: Ahh! not a problem I'll follow you there too ;)

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism do u have the same solution for magento2

Answer (score 3):

you can create and use `robots.txt` file. and you can add the urls which are not to be indexed.

create `robots.txt` file with following content

```
User-agent: *
# Paths (No clean URLs)
Disallow: /*?size=*
Disallow: /*?brands=*
Disallow: /*?price=*
Disallow: /*?dir=*
Disallow: /*?cat=*
```

and upload this file to the root dir of magento

Comment: Good suggestion but what if I've too many different filters for different products so in this case I've to add too many line in  .htaccess and I don't think it's proper solution for it.

Comment: you know the list of all product attributes which are  of type layered navigation and you need to add this in the robots.txt not in .htaccess file

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom extension for this. 
**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_MetaChange>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Custom_MetaChange>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <metaChange>
                <class>Custom_MetaChange_Model</class>
            </metaChange>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_layout_generate_xml_before>
                <observers>
                    <noindex>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>metaChange/observer</class>
                        <method>changeRobots</method>
                    </noindex>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_layout_generate_xml_before>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**Observer.php**

```
<?php

class Custom_MetaChange_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {

    public function changeRobots($observer) {

        $myaction = $observer->getEvent()->getAction();
        $uri = $myaction->getRequest()->getRequestUri();
        if (stristr($uri, "?")) {
            $actionname = $myaction->getFullActionName();
            if (($actionname == 'catalog_category_layered') || ($actionname == 'catalog_category_layered_nochildren')) {
                $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
                $product_info = $layout->getBlock('head');
                $layout->getUpdate()->addUpdate('<reference name="head"><action method="setRobots"><value>NOINDEX, FOLLOW</value></action></reference>');
                $layout->generateXml();
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```